# Give a Call to BroadCast Reciever Through An Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I am a newbie to Android development. I am trying to invent a broadcast receiver from my activity.

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context,"ABC", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String[] parameters= (String[])intent.getSerializableExtra("parameters");
    }
}
```

my activity is

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    public static String BROADCAST_ACTION="com.kiosk.cbal.CALL_RECEIVER";

    /**
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(Bundle)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String parameters = "safdsam,fdsa,fdsa,fdsa,fdsa";
        String[] parameters =abc.split(",");
        Intent i = new Intent("com.package.MyReceiver");
        i.putExtra("parameters", parameters);
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

My Manifest file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0"
    package="com.package" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MyActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="MyReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.kiosk.cbal.CALL_RECEIVER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver> 

    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS"/>
</manifest>
```

Now how I'll Be able to give a call to broadcast receiver through an activity?

Comment: You didn't ask a question.  That said, your action is "android.intent.action" -- there's an extra space there.  That string should be be used when you create the intent.  You can also simplify your string array initialization.

Comment: My Question is the title of my post what exactly i want to do. But by doing all this stuff I am unable to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the space from the action name.  Use the name when you create the Intent.

Comment: Hey earl thanks for your urgent reply but it was just an example android.intent.action.VIEW

Comment: Bad change.  You want that string to be unique to your broadcast and you want it to be the same string you pass to the Intent constructor.

Comment: No Not Exactly Earl. I have changed that thing to com.kiosk.cbal.CALL_RECEIVER this and also updated my Manifest file with this string com.kiosk.cbal.CALL_RECEIVER

Comment: Then the intent constructor is still getting the wrong string. it should be `Intent i = new Intent("com.kiosk.cbal.CALL_RECEIVER");`

Comment: Updated that but still no luck :(

Comment: It's also likely that you Receiver tag in your manifest is incorrect.  Look at [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html#nm).  You want a fully qualified class name or, if the class is in the package specified in the <manifest> element, a dot in front of the class name.

Comment: Thanks ALot Earl you are such a nice guy hope to find you more helpful in future :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** The code above still has `Intent i = new Intent("com.package.MyReceiver");`. It should be `Intent i = new Intent("com.kiosk.cbal.CALL_RECEIVER");`

Meanwhile, in your manifest the receiver name is specified as `<receiver android:name="MyReceiver">`. note that `android:name` must be either a fully qualified class name, or a name relative to the package name. The way `PackageManager` distinguishes the two is by the presence of a `.` at the beginning of the name. Thus, with your declaration, `PackageManager` is most likely attempting to instantiate `MyReceiver' instead of`com.package.MyReceiver`.

In any case, you should check the Android log file for details on what's going wrong with the intent you're broadcasting.

---

The string that you pass to the `Intent` constructor must be the same as the string specified for the action element for your receiver in the manifest. You are constructing the `Intent` with your receiver class name, but your receiver is declared to listen to the `VIEW` intent instead.